# using sinon to mock a line in a function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, chai, sinon

I have a function as follows

```
import config from "../config";
export const encrypt = (recordJSONy, logger) => {
const key =  config.encryption.key
if(!key || key == ""){
 throw encryptionError.ENCYPTION_KEY_MISSING
}
 try{
const decryptedDataStr = TisEncryption.Cipher.encrypt(recordJSON);
return decryptedDataStr;
} catch(e){
console.log(e)
throw encryptionError.ENCRYPTION_FAILED
}
}
```

I need to write a test for it

```
describe("help function test", () => {
it("test", () => {
console.log(helperFunctions.encrypt("xxx", loggingService))
});
});
```

However the above is always returning error because config.encryption.key returns undefined.
I am trying to find a way to kind of mock config.encryption.key to return "xxxxxxx" instead of undefined. The more I look at sinon the more I get confused. Can anyone shed light on how to do so?

Comment: Although `encrypt` using `config`, but I didn't know where is the config's source. So I suppose if the config of `encrypt` is exist on global scope, you can just defined a mock config on global scope before you run the unit testing.

Comment: @Clark config is another import where It contains some variable and they read their value from process.env

Comment: However I specifically needs to fix this using mocking... if possible to do so

Comment: You can just defined a `config` object and  the object's properties value in your test file, the `config` will be a mock.

Comment: can you give an example still I am not sure what you mean

Comment: The `config` you defined is a mock `config`, it isn't real value from process.env.

Comment: this is part of my config file:   encryption: {
    key: process.env.CIPHER_KEY,
  }

Comment: I made a simple example you can check: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-fast-j1wxk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: @Clark Thanks a lot for your help  but in that case we are sending the config as a parameter